Issues with CASE Statement in Looker Studio
I’m having trouble with a CASE statement in Looker Studio. The formula is supposed to return 1 based on specific conditions, but it’s not working as expected. Here is the formula:
    CASE 
      WHEN [activity_category] = 'onqueuework' 
           AND CAST([activity_duration] AS INT64) >= 120 
           AND [activity_name] = 'onqueuework' 
           AND COUNT(DISTINCT IF([activity_category] = 'onqueuework', [agent_name])) = 1 
        THEN 1 

      WHEN [activity_category] = 'timeoff' 
           AND (CAST([activity_duration] AS INT64) >= 120 
                OR (CAST([activity_duration] AS INT64) = 30 
                    AND [activity_name] = 'loa uto' 
                    AND COUNT(DISTINCT IF([activity_category] = 'timeoff', [agent_name])) = 1)) 
        THEN 1 

      WHEN [activity_category] = 'onqueuework' 
           AND CAST([activity_duration] AS INT64) = 30 
           AND [activity_name] = 'overtime' 
           AND COUNT(DISTINCT IF([activity_category] = 'onqueuework', [agent_name])) = 1 
        THEN 1 
      ELSE 0 
    END

What I tried: I used the above CASE statement to categorize activities based on specific conditions. I expected the formula to return 1 when the conditions are met and 0 otherwise.
What I expected:

Return 1 if activity_category is ‘onqueuework’, activity_duration is 120 or more, activity_name is ‘onqueuework’, and the count of distinct agent_name for ‘onqueuework’ is 1.

Return 1 if activity_category is ‘timeoff’, activity_duration is 120 or more, or activity_duration is 30, activity_name is ‘loa uto’, and the count of distinct agent_name for ‘timeoff’ is 1.

Return 1 if activity_category is ‘onqueuework’, activity_duration is 30, activity_name is ‘overtime’, and the count of distinct agent_name for ‘onqueuework’ is 1.


What happened: The formula doesn’t seem to be working correctly. It doesn’t return the expected results for some of the conditions. In Looker Studio it says, Invalid Formula - invalid input expression. Unsupported expression
Could someone identify what might be wrong or suggest any improvements?
